# Why this 0 in ((type*)0)->member in C?

Tags: c, kernel

The [`container_of()`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.12/include/linux/kernel.h#L792) macro in the Linux kernel is defined as:

```
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({ \
        const typeof( ((type*)0)->member) * __mptr =(ptr);\
        (type*)( (char*)__mptr - offsetof(type,member) );})
```

Why does this use `((type*)0)->member`, not `(type*)->member`?

Comment: It looks like someone is trying to cast null to type*, then access it's member member.

Comment: @Nocturno Not just trying. :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Why this is ((type*)0)->member, not (type*)->member

Simply because `(type*)->member` would be invalid syntax, thus `typeof` would be impossible. So it uses a `NULL` pointer, which it doesn't dereference anyway - it's used just so `typeof` can refer to the member.

---

How this works:

- The `typeof` trick is used to declare a pointer of the type of the member. This pointer gets is initialized with the pointer passed by the caller
- The offset of that member in the struct is subtracted from the address of the pointer: this yields the address of the containing object

---

Subtler issue: **why not get rid of `typeof`** and just do `ptr - offsetof`. We're casting it to `char *` anyway, right ? In that case you could pass anything as `ptr` and the compiler won't say a thing. So the whole `typeof` things is there for (rudimentary) type checking.

Answer (score 9):

Because `type*` is a type and not a valid instance of the structure.

The pointer to zero is used to get a proper instance, but as `typeof` is resolved at compile-time and not at run-time the address used in the pointer doesn't have to be a proper or valid address.